# Hotel Portal - Tourist Guide - Joomla templates

Tags: templates, joomla, portal

Any good joomla template that you can suggest to me for building a hotel portal and a tourist guide for my area?

I found ja_travel but if anybody knows one that will be more suitable, please let me know.

Other than joomla, are there any other good templates for wp or drupal?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple templares from various companies that I would recommend for Joomla.

On the commercial side, I would recommend anything from [Yootheme](http://yootheme.com) or [Rockettheme](http://rockettheme.com). Some of their templates can be rather heavy but they are very professional and definitely worth the money. Yootheme also have their master theme available for free download if you were interested in a bit of editing. All the templates you see on their site are also available for wordpress too.

As for non-commercial templates you will have to look around for some good ones. Most free templates are very basic and bland. I have come across a few that I like such as [JA Elastica](http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-elastica) and [YooGrids](http://www.youjoomla.com/yougrids-free-joomla-template-yjsg-powered.html). Both includes their own frameworks, making them much more flexible.

There are no specific extensions for hotels that I know of however there IS a category on JED for real-estate. Im am pretty sure on one these extensions can be used for hotels.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate

There are 3 in the list for Joomla 2.5 that are free:

[Real Estate Manager Basic](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/8529)

[JEA](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/6755)

[FW Real Estate Light](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/13376)

Comment: Are you aware of any (all-in-one) component that I can use in order to present each hotel separately including hotel facilities, photos, contact form?